# add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddHealthChecks'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I am using ASP.NET Core 3, .NET Core 3.0.100, Visual Studio 2019 Community. I follow this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-3.0?view=aspnetcore-3.0#health-checks

In `Startup.cs`, I add `endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");`

```cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {         

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Error

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddHealthChecks' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.HealthCheckEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapHealthChecksCore(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, String pattern, HealthCheckOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.HealthCheckEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapHealthChecks(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, String pattern)
   at foo.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__5_0(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) in C:\Users\donhuvy\Desktop\acc133b3\acc133blazor\Startup.cs:line 104
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at foo.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in C:\Users\donhuvy\Desktop\acc133b3\acc133blazor\Startup.cs:line 98
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.<StartAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I've received this when I'd accidentally removed one line from Startup.cs ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The exception message clearly indicates that your should invoke `services.AddHealthChecks()` inside `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

> Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddHealthChecks' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.

```
void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    //...

    services.AddHealthChecks();

    //...
}
```

#### Reference [Health checks in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks)

Comment: Good answer. Only saw half of the solution

Answer (score 24):

Most likely you forgot to add to ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc();
```

Comment: Works, thanks! How come the .NET AspMvcCore project template doesn't include this in its bioler plate code?